# Nomenclature of Electronic states

Tags: physical-chemistry

We often see electronic states are named like nπ* or ππ* states. What is the reason behind this kind of naming ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE!  At this point I suggest that you take the short [tour] of the site.  Best of luck...

Comment: Can you give specific examples? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at the labels of electronic transitions? For example $\mathrm{n-\pi^*}$ would be the the transition of an electron from a nonbonding orbital to a $\pi$ antibonding orbital.

Comment: As @Ben Norris writes the $\pi\pi^*$  refer to electronic transitions between states. The notation is just a simplification/shorthand to indicate the type of molecular orbitals the HOMO /LUMO electrons are in, rather than using proper symmetry labels.